# How to rank the categorical values while one-hot-encoding

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have the data like this.

| id | feature_1 | feature_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | e |
| 2 | b | c |
| 3 | c | d |
| 4 | d | b |
| 5 | e | a |

I want the one-hot-encoded like feature with the first column representing 1 and the second column representing 0.5. Like the following table.

| id | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0.5 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0.5 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0.5 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 0.5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

But when applying `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`
it outputs 10 columns with respective 1s.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the two columns, you can do:

```
pd.crosstab(df.id, df.feature_1) + pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['feature_2']) * .5
```

Output:

```
feature_1    a    b    c    d    e
id                                
1          1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5
2          0.0  1.0  0.5  0.0  0.0
3          0.0  0.0  1.0  0.5  0.0
4          0.0  0.5  0.0  1.0  0.0
5          0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

If you have more than two features, with the weights defined, then you can `melt` then map the features to the weights:

```
weights = {'feature_1':1, 'feature_2':0.5}
flatten = df.melt('id')

(flatten['variable'].map(weights)
     .groupby([flattern['id'], flatten['value']])
     .sum().unstack('value', fill_value=0)
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Quang Hoang, This works as expected.
I only have 2 features. But keep in head for more weighted features in the futures. Thank you again!! Sorry for couldn't upvote your answer as my reputation is low.